mlflow.transformers.load_model() from mlflow server throws error, whereas loading from local file works
Problem
When trying to load a logged (=saved) peft model from mlflow server, I get an Error(s) in loading state_dict for PeftModelForCausalLM: size mismatch. When I load the very same model from a local file, it works :thinking:
I'm on mlflow 2.15.1 and transformers 4.42.4.
Any ideas how to solve this?
Example
Logging a peft model to mlflow
import mlflow
import torch
from peft import LoraConfig, get_peft_model
from transformers import (
    AutoModelForCausalLM,
    AutoTokenizer,
    BitsAndBytesConfig,
    TrainingArguments,
)
from trl import SFTTrainer, setup_chat_format

train_dataset = ...
eval_dataset = ...

model_id = "LeoLM/leo-hessianai-7b-chat-bilingual"

# Load model and tokenizer
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    device_map="auto",
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
tokenizer_no_pad = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id, add_bos_token=True)
model, tokenizer = setup_chat_format(model, tokenizer)
peft_config = LoraConfig(...)
args = TrainingArguments(...)

peft_model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)

# Define Trainer
trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=peft_model,
    args=args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    peft_config=peft_config,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    packing=True,
)

# mlflow
mlflow.set_experiment("my_experiment")
with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    mlflow.transformers.autolog()
    
    trainer.train()
    trainer.save_model()
    
    components = {
         "model": trainer.model,
         "tokenizer": tokenizer_no_pad,
     }
     mlflow.transformers.log_model(
         transformers_model=components,
         artifact_path="model",
    )

del model
del trainer
torch.cuda.empty_cache()

✔️ Loading peft model from local file --- works ---
local_peft_model = "models/leo-hessianai-7b-chat-bilingual"
# Load Model with PEFT adapter
model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    local_peft_model, device_map="auto", torch_dtype=torch.float16
)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(local_peft_model)
pipe = pipeline("text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

❌  Loading peft model via mlflow.transformers.load_model() ---does not work---
model_from_mlflow = mlflow.transformers.load_model(
    "mlflow-artifacts:/path/to/artifacts/peft_model",
)  

Throws this error:
Downloading artifacts: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [01:31<00:00,  9.15s/it]
Downloading artifacts: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  9.40it/s]
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:04<00:00,  2.40s/it]
Special tokens have been added in the vocabulary, make sure the associated word embeddings are fine-tuned or trained.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/git_repos/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/utils/docstring_utils.py", line 423, in version_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/git_repos/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/transformers/__init__.py", line 1033, in load_model
    return _load_model(local_model_path, flavor_config, return_type, device, **kwargs)
  File "/git_repos/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/transformers/__init__.py", line 1221, in _load_model
    model_and_components[FlavorKey.MODEL] = get_model_with_peft_adapter(
  File "/git_repos/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/transformers/peft.py", line 50, in get_model_with_peft_adapter
    return PeftModel.from_pretrained(base_model, peft_adapter_path)
  File "/git_repos/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/peft/peft_model.py", line 430, in from_pretrained
    model.load_adapter(model_id, adapter_name, is_trainable=is_trainable, **kwargs)
  File "/git_repos/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/peft/peft_model.py", line 988, in load_adapter
    load_result = set_peft_model_state_dict(
  File "/git_repos/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/peft/utils/save_and_load.py", line 353, in set_peft_model_state_dict
    load_result = model.load_state_dict(peft_model_state_dict, strict=False)
  File "/git_repos/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 2215, in load_state_dict
    raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for PeftModelForCausalLM:
        size mismatch for base_model.model.model.embed_tokens.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([32007, 4096]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([32128, 4096]).
        size mismatch for base_model.model.lm_head.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([32007, 4096]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([32128, 4096]).

I honestly don't know where ths size mismatches of the models comes from...
I have tried to resize the token embeddings to match the tokenizer's vocabulary size via model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer)) - which did not help, and I have set the max_seq_length=512 (a rather low value), which did also not help...
Any ideas how to either get the size problem fixed or make mlflow.transformers.load_model behave the way a local loading does?
